# Designing Data storage for a E-commerce website

Tags: database-design, e-commerce

I am trying to understand how E-commerce sites handle huge amount of inventory and the transactions associated with it. With respect to this, i have some basic questions.

Consider a E-commerce website running on multiple servers
and the inventory associated with it is small and can fit inside a single server.

Where should this inventory be kept? In a centralized server or should it be replicated in each server where the web app is running?

Consider two users whose request being handled by different servers, contest for the same product.

If the inventory is replicated in each server, then the transactions can't be synchronized. Or is there any synchronization mechanism which works across multiple servers?

And if the inventory is kept in a centralized server and if all web apps have to query this centralized server, then the issue is it takes more time for the transaction.

How do websites resolve above problem?

Suppose if the inventory is huge, is a distributed database way to go?

With respect to distributed databases:

1. Do distributed databases inherently have mechanisms to handle above issue(contesting for the same product)? And How did E-commerce sites handle this issue when there were no distributed databases?
2. Can a relational database be distributed?
3. Can a typical inventory be modeled as a non-relational database?

I understand that these are some basic questions, i am just starting to learn about E-commerce and building scalable web applications, so any resources or learning materials to get answers to the questions i mentioned above is appreciated.

Comment: Try downloading and installing "Magento".  It is a FOSS E-Commerce package used by several large online retailers so it can cope with high volumes.  Look at the documentation especially around performance if you wish to see how they handle distributed multi-server architecture.

Comment: use a powerful matured framework like spring boot or django or laravel. You can get many features out of the box.

Comment: databases have active data and passive data. you can use multiple dbms from different vendors to serve your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I am working as a developer for a big e-commerce system. We are using one database (oracle) and 1..n nodes of an backend and frontend. Each node has own cache, we are using events to invalidate it within a cluster.

> Consider two users whose request being handled by different servers, contest for the same product.

In solution as my company is using, regular transactions are enough to handle such scenario.

> How do websites resolve above problem?

I think there is many approaches to handle this issue, which also depends of the technology you would like to use. You can go as we did with one database or you could go for microservices approach or somehow mix it. Each solution has is pluses and minuses.